# Change class when form modified

Tags: jquery, forms, onchange

So I've been looking through all the information I can gather and I came up with the following code:

```
$('form :input').change(function () {
  $('.save-changes').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');
});
```

What I'm trying to do is detect any change in the entire form, and change a button's class to remind the user they'll need to click "Save changes" before the changes actually take effect.

Unfortunately, being new to jQuery, I can't seem to figure out why my code isn't working. Any help would be very appreciated!

Here's the HTML for the button (but I doubt the problem lies there):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default full-width save-changes" value="submit">Save changes</button>
```

Oh, and I put the jQuery directly into the page's source code between `<script>` tags.

As requested, I created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eg8a5x37/1/

Comment: create a jsfiddle please?

Comment: See updated question ^

Comment: You need to include the jquery in `$(document).ready`. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eg8a5x37/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really only need to perform this in a document ready event for it to work.

```
$(function() {
$('form :input').change(function () {
    $('.save-changes').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');
});
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eg8a5x37/3/

Comment: That worked! I also included the jQuery inside `$(document).ready` and moved all my scripts right before the `</body>` tag after reading it was better that way.